# Shadowbox not working once loaded to server

Tags: javascript, html, gallery, shadowbox

Shadowbox will not work once I publish my page via yahoo sitebuilder and load in either google or ie. I don't understand why. Maybe it's in the code:

HTML for the page head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Jason\sitebuilder\sites\UltimateFinishAutoDetailing\files\shadowbox\shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Jason\sitebuilder\sites\UltimateFinishAutoDetailing\files\shadowbox\shadowbox.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Shadowbox.init();

HTML for the element on the page (where i have a thumbnail that is supposed to,once clicked, pop up in shadowbox. For some reason though, it opens up in another page without shadowbox.):

```
<a href="images/IMG00248-20110527-17522.jpg" rel="shadowbox">
<img src="sitebuilder/images/IMG00248-20110527-17522-100x75.jpg">
</a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js and css (C:\User..) are pointing to local paths, it will not work on server. use url or relative paths if the files are in server. 
Upload the css and js and keep it in same server folder and work like this ...

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js">      </script>
```

OR if u have url's then use them on src & href accordingly.